# Por qué se me suman más números al usar HighCharts?

Tags: php, html, laravel, highcharts

estoy intentando graficar unos datos y al momento de pasar los datos al gráfico este me suma más decimales de los que debería mostrar, adjunto imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se fijan, adultos en el gráfico tiene 2,59% más que en la tabla, entonces, no tengo mucha idea de qué podría ser...

adjunto script y consulta

```
Highcharts.chart('chartRangoR2', {
            colors: ['#9149c4', '#3e962c', '#F7A35C', '#dd5e5e'],
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Rango Etario',
                align: 'center'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.2f}%</b>'
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            accessibility: {
                point: {
                    valueSuffix: '%'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.2f} %'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Brands',
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [{
                        name: 'Niños',
                        y: @foreach ($rangoEtarioR2 as $item)
                            {{ $item->nino }}
                        @endforeach
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Jovenes',
                        y: @foreach ($rangoEtarioR2 as $item)
                            {{ $item->joven }}
                        @endforeach
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Adultos',
                        y: @foreach ($rangoEtarioR2 as $item)
                            {{ $item->adulto }}
                        @endforeach
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Adulto Mayor',
                        y: @foreach ($rangoEtarioR2 as $item)
                            {{ $item->anciano }}
                        @endforeach
                    }
                ]
            }]
        });
```

```
        $rangoEtarioR2 = DB::connection('mysql_2')->select(DB::raw('SELECT hombres, mujeres,truncate(`1`,"2") nino, truncate(`2`,"2") adolecente, truncate(`3`,"2") joven, truncate(`4`,"2") adulto, truncate(`5`,"2") anciano, time 
                                                                    FROM personas_rf_dia
                                                                    WHERE id = 2'));
```

La tabla que está debajo del chart está recogiendo los mismos datos del gráfico, por eso me estoy guiando, adjunto también el código de la tabla

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                Ítem
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Rango
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Porcentaje
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                Niños
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                0 - 11
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @foreach ($rangoEtarioR2 as $item)
                                                    {{ number_format($item->nino, 2, ',', '.') }}%
                                                @endforeach
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                Adolecentes
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                12 - 18
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @foreach ($rangoEtarioR2 as $item)
                                                    {{ number_format($item->adolecente, 2, ',', '.') }}%
                                                @endforeach
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                Joven
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                19 - 26
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @foreach ($rangoEtarioR2 as $item)
                                                    {{ number_format($item->joven, 2, ',', '.') }}%
                                                @endforeach
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                Adulto
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                27 - 59
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @foreach ($rangoEtarioR2 as $item)
                                                    {{ number_format($item->adulto, 2, ',', '.') }}%
                                                @endforeach
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                Adulto Mayor
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                60 +
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @foreach ($rangoEtarioR2 as $item)
                                                    {{ number_format($item->anciano, 2, ',', '.') }}%
                                                @endforeach
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Me he estado craneando todo el día y no logro entender que es lo que está pasando, quizá algo en el caché, no lo sé, si alguien puede ayudarme con esto lo agradecería muchísimo, ya que todo esto es para mi trabajo y no entiendo que pasa! jajaja

Esta es la salida que da la consulta en la base de datos, los datos cambiaron pq se ejecuta cada 15 minutos un script automatico, pero no tiene nada que ver con los datos erroneos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Podrías añadir una salida de ejemplo de la consulta? Qué se obtiene al ejecutar esa consulta tal cual en la BD?

Comment: Listo listo, ahí está

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El *error* se da porque, mientras en la tabla tienes 5 datos, y los porcentajes suman 100%, a la gráfica le pasas solamente 4 datos, cuyos porcentajes solo suman 94.59%, pero el *pie* siempre debe contener un 100% en total.

Por esta razón, el componente de gráfica hace una regla de 3, veamos el caso del grupo Adulto:

```
45.27 es a 94.59%
    x es a 100%    

x = 45.27*100/94.59 = 47.8592%
```

Por esa razón es que muestra el valor de 47.86%.

La solución genérica al problema es pasar los mismos datos a la tabla y al gráfico.

Si necesitas excluir al grupo de adolescentes de la gráfica, mi sugerencia es que lo quites también de la tabla y hagas la misma regla de 3 que te muestro para re-calcular los porcentajes que se imprimen en la tabla.

La otra posible solución es que incluyas al grupo de Adolescentes también en la gráfica, en cuyo caso los porcentajes mostrados si que coincidirán.